# Where is the L stone?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've found every stones but the L.
I may have missed a room, but I can't find which one... Is it in the spiky room (castle)? I think it's the only one I didn't entirely get through for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The L stone is in the room with the giant face monster. Simply carry no weapon, waltz in there and take the stone.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the castle room with the eggs and a creature that drops on top of you, to get it you must *not* attack the eggs (i.e, don't equip damaging items).

Answer (score 1):

From the [candy box 2 wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_L_stone)

> The L stone is hidden in the chest inside the upper room in the castle area.
>   Inside this room, you can see the chest at the end with a lot of eggs in between and a monster floating near the ceiling. Walking up to the chest and breaking any of the eggs will cause the monster to instantly rush and kill you. The solution to avoiding the eggs should be pretty obvious.